# Detect if running from published self-contained executable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Is there a simple way to detect if a .NET Core app is running from `dotnet` installed on the system or self-contained distribution?

I am working on a build automation script that requires some knowledge about relative paths and entry point for creating dependent processes with cli args.

I am Using .NET Core and publish self-contained app that creates `myapp.exe`. During design and debug time the program is run with `dotnet` command and I use the following to start another process with specific cli args:

```
var filename = typeof(Program).Assembly.Location; // .../myapp.dll
var argsString = string.Join(" ", args);
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Arguments = filename + " " + argsString, 
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                FileName = "dotnet",
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
            };
```

But then in self-contained application the file name should be `FileName = "myapp.exe"` and `Arguments = argsString`. However, the property `typeof(Program).Assembly.Location` still returns `myapp.dll`, because `myapp.exe` is a wrapper over distributed copy of `dotnet` packed with the self-contained app and it calls the same `myapp.dll`.

Without knowing where I am running from I need to change the parameters every time I publish the app, which significantly slows down development and makes build automation much harder.

Is there a "normal" - i.e. supported by the framework with some property or methods - way to detect this, without checking if `myapp.exe` is present in the working directory or some other heuristic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is redirected to your .dll, but you should be able to see the real executable with Process.  Eg

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Which is more of an an OS-level API.

Answer (score 3):

It was a wrong direction/approach.

To achieve what I wanted:

**a.** Build -> Configuration Manager... -> New Config

**b.** Name it e.g. `Publish`

**c.** Add the following to `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Publish'">
  <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);PUBLISHED</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**d.** Use the newlly created `Publish` config in `dotnet publish` or from VS `Publish...` wizard.

**e.** Use from code:

```
#if PUBLISHED
            Console.WriteLine("+++++++++++ Running from published +++++++++++++");
#endif
```

Comment: That's a good approach.  Also could use `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Great, exactly what I *asked*. Post it as an answer and it's yours! :)